# Select rows from IList based on column value not null .net

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have an IList that pretty much emulates the following table:

| Code | Year | Type | Value | Active | Paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2009 | Lic | NULL | True | 3.12 |
| ABC | 2009 | Car | Audi | True | 4.63 |
| ABC | 2010 | Lic | Learner | True | 5.41 |
| ABC | 2011 | Lic | Full | True | 7.82 |
| ABC | 2011 | Car | Honda | True | 5.19 |
| ABC | 2012 | Lic | Expired | True | 10.50 |
| ABC | 2013 | Lic | NULL | True | 15.71 |
| XYZ | 2009 | Lic | NULL | True | 4.63 |
| XYZ | 2010 | Lic | Full | True | 6.90 |
| XYZ | 2010 | Car | Mazda | True | 4.29 |
| XYZ | 2011 | Lic | Full | True | 9.73 |
| XYZ | 2011 | Car | Mazda | True | 9.17 |

Each Code will have multiple Types, each with annual data. The amount of annual data for different Types for a single Code may differ.

I'm bringing it into a method as variable yv.

I have the following code to obtain the range of years of data, but I want to exclude those where Lic = NULL and the below returns all years in the DB. I'll later use the valid (Lic != NULL) years to do other calculations.

Also, advice on how to store the valid years so that they can be accessed by other methods doing other calculations that only need the valid years' data would also be appreciated. I'm out of my depth on this one.

```
public decimal RegoCosts(IList<YearlyValuesTable> yv) 
{
  IList<string> years = yv.Select(x => x.Year).Distinct().ToList();
  // other magic not relevant to this question
  return avePaidYearly;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: what about `yv.Where(x => x.Type != "Lic" || x.Value != null)`?

Comment: @dave-f Did you see MakePeaceGreatAgain's suggestion? Their proposed statement would give you the valid `YearlyValuesTable` items in `yv` (as per your requirement of excluding items having `Type ==" Lic"` and `Value == null`). To get only the years from that selection, you can add your already proposed querying to that result: `.Select(x => x.Year).Distinct().ToList();`

Comment: I've seen the responses, I just haven't had a chance to try them to see what they give me. Sorry - it's been a rough few days. Will hopefully be able to by Monday night

Comment: Thanks @MakePeaceGreatAgain, I changed the line to `IList<string> years = yv.Where(x => x.Type != "Lic" && x.Value != null).Select(x => x.Year).Distinct().ToList();` and I get the number of years I'm after. Post that and I'll award you the answer. Thanks @Astrid for the suggestion. While I can't give bonus points, the syntax to reduce yv so it doesn't contain any rows for a year where Lic = Null would be super helpful (i.e. No rows for ABC for 2009)

Comment: @DaveF No need to apologize; I simply wanted to check in case you had overlooked it, as I honestly thought their suggestion would be what you needed. With your latest comment, I see that I have misunderstood slightly, and that you need something a little more complex than what has been suggested here in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter out all entries that

1. *either* have `Type = "Lic"` and `Value = null`,
2. *or* contain a `Code` and `Year` combination that matches an entry fulfilling the above condition,

you could group your entries by `Code` and `Year` using [`.GroupBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0), and then filter each *code and year* group using the predicate of the filter expression originally suggested by @MakePeaceGreatAgain in their comment.

After that filtering, you are left with a nested collection of `YearlyValuesTable` objects, which is flattened to a non-nested collection using [`.SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0).

```csharp
IList<YearlyValuesTable> validEntries = yv
    .GroupBy(entry => ( entry.Code, entry.Year ))
    .Where(entriesByCodeAndYear => 
        entriesByCodeAndYear.All(entry => entry.Type != "Lic" || entry.Value != null))
    .SelectMany(_ => _)
    .ToList();
```

---

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xar63d).

Comment: What I like about this is that is cleans the null Lic years out entirely, so I can than count the remaining years of `validEntries` instead of yv. Thank you for the response (and for pointing me to Fiddle. That will de-risk my PoCs while I get my head around Git in VS)

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right for the first question you want to get the range of years every code has, without counting the lines where value == null, so for example "ABC" will have 2010-2011-2012, if that's the case you can try something like this:

```
public class listSetup()
{
  public string CodeName { get; set; }
  public List<int> Years { get; set; }

  //put a empty contructor
}
```

and then

```
var newList = new List<ListSetup>();

newList.add(new ListSetup(){
  CodeName = yv[0].Code,
  Years = new List<int>()
});  

for(int row = 0; row < yv.Count; row++)
{
  if(newList.Last().CodeName != yv[row].Code)
  {
    //If code is changed distinct the Years in the code before
    newList.Last().Years = newList.Last().Years.distinct().toList();      

    newList.add(new ListSetup(){
      CodeName = yv[row].Code,
      Years = new List<int>()
    });
  }
  
  if(yv[row].Value != null)
  {
    newList.Last().Years.Add(yv[row].Year)
  }
}
```

This one should leave you with a list that contains the "code name" and a distinct list of "years" for every code in your list, and maybe this can even facilitate the second question for you.

EDIT: If you want to only remove the lines where Value == null from the list yv you can semplify the code like this:

```
int LinesInYV = yv.Count;

for(int row = 0; row < LinesInYV; row++)
{
  if(yv[row] != null)
  {
    if(yv[row].Value == null)
    {
      yv.RemoveAt(row);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Looking at those last 3 lines, is there a similar syntax that would solve both my problems by removing all rows with the same year as the Lic = Null year from yv?

Comment: You could do that adding a similar If condition in the same cycle, for example `If(yv[row].CodeName == yv[row - 1].CodeName && yv[row].Year == yv[row - 1].Year){ yv.RemoveAt(row); }`  This check if you get 2 consecutive rows with the same year and code and then deletes the first one found, let me know if this helps  PS: I updated the last row of the last code sample for a little error